# I can't input the obelus(division symbol) in edittext android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

The title says it all. I am trying to make a calculator and of course, a calculator has a division symbol. The text of the button in the XML file can be changed to an obelus but pressing the button can't input the symbol in the Edittext. Instead, a diamond with a questionmark pops out instead. I am also having a problem with the multiplication symbol(not just the letter x but the right multiplication symbol)

Here is a code snippet:

```
if(Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(temp.length()-1))) {
                            editText.append("÷");
                            decf = 2;
                            ansf = 0;
                            btnDel.setText("DEL");
                        }
```

Comment: I don't seem to be having an issue with this when I create a quick example, I can set the button value as "÷" and populate EditText with setText. Can you post some code?

Comment: there. it appends a diamond with a question mark instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to be an encoding issue. Try "\u00F7"

Here's the docs:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm